# $location and $locationProvider

Tags: angularjs, initialization, location-provider

I'm trying to create a variable link in an angular app. If it is mobile, it will open the href in a new tab. If it is desktop, it will open in a popup. As such, I am trying to invoke the $location variable provided by Angular, but cannot figure out to invoke it. Where/how do I initialize the use of this variable?

Comment: need to look at your code

Comment: $location is a service. You inject it into your controller like any other service. This is covered by the angular documentation.